# Proving that $\lim\limits_{R\to\infty}\int_0^\pi e^{-R\sin\theta}d\theta=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, analysis, limits

I want to show that the limit below is zero.
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_0^\pi e^{-R\sin\theta}d\theta$$
*Wolframalpha* and my intuition say that the limit is truly zero but I cannot approach.

Any hints will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think you can use the Dominated Convergence Theorem to pass the limit through the integral sign.

Comment: there is a really famous inequality for the sine function..

Comment: I missed the very easy point. Thanks, especially for @tired .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very nice question.

First split the integral involves  at $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ then take the change of variable $\theta'=\pi -\theta$

$$ \int_0^\pi e^{-R\sin\theta}d\theta =2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-R\sin\theta}d\theta$$

afterward shows by studying the function $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\ni\theta \mapsto\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}$ that

$$ \color{blue}{\sin\theta \geq \frac{2}{\pi}\theta ~~ \forall \theta\in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}] } $$
therefore we get that 
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-R\sin\theta}d\theta\leq\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-\frac{2R}{\pi}\theta}d\theta =\lim_{R\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{2R}(1-e^{-R}) =0$$